# How do I integrate the current Google Play Billing Library with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, google-play-billing

A warning titled "Google Play Billing Library version deprecation" is displayed in the "Products->In-App Products" menu on the Google Play Console page. How can I solve this?

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/deprecation-faq